# Sort Array of Objects based on class member variables in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, object, member

As an example, say I have a Book class and a BookInventory class. The book class has member variables "IDstring" for example:

```
class Book {
private:
    string IDstring; // this is made up. A string of letters and nums
    int numPages;
public:
    Book(string IDstring, int numPages);
    void setIDstring(string IDstring);
    string getIDstring();
    void setNumPages(int numPages);
    int getNumPages();
};
```

etc... and a the BookInventory class which stores the books:

```
class BookInventory {
private:
    int numBooks;
    BookArray **book;
public:
    BookInventory(int stock);
    void sortBooks();
    void insertBook(Book *book);
};
```

Something like that. 
How Would I sort the books by their string attribute IDstring (which contains both letters and numbers i.e. 15C6HQP9), in alphabetical (or numerical when appropriate) order). 
In, the example above, I create a array of pointers to pointers with BookArray **book;, because a larger project than the one above requires this type of array.

Comment: Have you learned about std::sort yet?

Comment: Sorting alphabetically and numerically is tricky. If the numbers are 1, 10 and 2, is 10 before 2 or after? Also a double pointer doesn't tell us the required structure of the arrays. Is it a 2d array or something? This is why containers should be preferred.

Comment: I've seen the syntax just looking through code, but haven't learned about it. I am new to C++

Comment: @NeilKirk it is a 1d array, and assume the digits are just 0-9

Comment: So each book is dynamically allocated? And what exactly is type `BookArray`?

Comment: std::Sort by default uses a lexicographical_Compare<> to sort the strings..If you still want to use your own comparator, provide it to std::sort